# Uploading a file to imgur using PHP Imgurv3 API

Tags: php, curl, imgur

I writing a webapp which uploads images to imgur directly. Since all older version of their APIs have been deprecated i am forced to use v3 of their APIs. Unfortunately I am unable to get the API to work. I am using curl to access the API.

```
$pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
$timeout = 30;
$curl    = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID xxxxxxa61xxxxxx'));
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
$xmlsimple = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print gettype($xml)."<hr>";
echo '<img height="180" src="';
echo $xmlsimple->links->original;
echo '">';
curl_close ($curl);
```

The "Xml" variable always return as "false", no server error is displayed. Can someone guide me to what I am doing wrong ? Unfortunately I am also unable to find any proper example in the documentation nor around to guide me.

I've just tried the code from another question on stack overflow but I am still getting the same problem.

```
    var_dump(base64_encode($data));
echo "<hr>";

$client_id = "xxxxxxa61xxxxxx";
$url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json';
$headers = array("Authorization: Client-ID $client_id");
$pvars  = array('image' => base64_encode($data));

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL=> $url,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_POST => 1,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $pvars
));

$json_returned = curl_exec($curl); // blank response
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
echo "<hr>";

echo "Result: " . $json_returned ;
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($json_returned);
echo "<hr>";

curl_close ($curl);
```

Comment: Array ( [url] => https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.404 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 1.404 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 23.21.176.50 [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 192.168.42.208 [local_port] => 49599

Comment: ^This is a dump of the $curl variable